# Getting Supported WiFi Data rates in Android

Tags: android, android-wifi

I've looked through the Android API methods and can't find this. Hope you can help.

My app needs to be able to determine ALL the WiFi data rates supported by the device the app is running on. It also needs to get the same information from the access point / router it is connected to. Possible?

I am not looking for [WiFiInto getLinkSpeed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiInfo.html#getLinkSpeed%28%29).

Comment: Thanks, Sam. That's what I feared. Is it possible to go around the API directly to the wireless driver?

Answer (score 0):

This information isn't provided by any Android API as far as I am aware.